# Fastest Python GLPK linear program solver

Tags: python, linear-programming, glpk

Does anyone with a lot of experience know the fastest package for solving linear programs in Python? Or can point me in the right direction?

I have built some code that takes in hourly records for market prices from a number of different source and chooses which market to participate in given a big list (10-20) of constraints based on timing and combination.

Comment: Commercial solvers (such as Cplex and Gurobi) are much, much faster than open source solvers.

Comment: This question is missing all the details and shows some lack of research. In terms of LP, open-source solvers can be somewhat competitive. But this might change drastically for MIPs.